# Sign up script security check

Tags: php, mysql

Hey guys, I have this sign up script and I'm using mysql_real_escape_string .I know prepared statements are safer but I'm just not experienced enough to use them, I just can't figure out how. Anyway here's the script:

```
<?php

    $username=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $password=sha1($_POST['password']);
    $password2=sha1($_POST['password_confirmation']);
    $passcheck=$_POST['password'];
    $todo=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['todo']);
    $email=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $fname=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fname']);
    $lname=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lname']);
    $gender=$_POST['gender'];
    $class=$_POST['class'];
    $section=$_POST['section'];



if(isset($todo) and $todo=="post"){

    $status = "OK";
    $msg="";
    }

if(!isset($username) OR strlen($username) <3){
    $msg=$msg."Username should be equal to or more than 3 characters long.<BR/>";
    $status= "NOTOK";
    }                   

if(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = '$username'"))){
$msg=$msg."Username already exists. Please try another one.<BR/>";
$status= "NOTOK";
}

if(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = '$email'"))){
$msg=$msg."E-mail is already in use. Please try again.<BR/>";
$status= "NOTOK";
}                                       


if ( strlen($passcheck) < 3 ){
    $msg=$msg."Password must be more than 3 charactors long.<BR/>";
    $status= "NOTOK";
    }                   

if ( $password <> $password2 ){
    $msg=$msg."Passwords are not identical.<BR/>";
    $status= "NOTOK";
    }                   
if(!eregi("^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$", $email)){
    $msg=$msg."The email is not a valid email.<br/>";
    $status="NOTOK";
    }

if($status=="NOTOK"){
    echo '<div class="statusmsg">'.$msg.'<br/><input class="submitButton" type="button" value="Retry" onClick="location.href='."'signup.php'\"></div>";
}
    else {
        $hash = md5( rand(0,1000) );
        $hash = mysql_real_escape_string($hash);
if(mysql_query("insert into users(username,password,email,fname,lname,hash,gender,class,section) values('$username','$password','$email','$fname','$lname','$hash','$gender','$class','$section')")or die (mysql_error ())){
    echo '<div class="statusmsg">Welcome, You have successfully signed up. Please check the verification e-mail sent to you.</div>';
    $to = $email; 
   $subject = 'Signup | Verification'; 
   $message = ' 

        Thanks for signing up! 
            Your account has been created, you can login with the following credentials after you have activated your account by pressing the url below. 

            ------------------------ 
            Username: '.$username.' 
        ------------------------ 

        Please click this link to activate your account: 
   <div id="header">  
         <h3>JMToday > Sign up</h3>  
     </div>         
        http://www.JMtoday.com/verification.php?email='.$email.'&hash='.$hash.' 

   ';

    $headers = 'From:noreply@JMtoday.com' . "\r\n";  
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); 
    }
else { 
echo "Database problem, please contact site admin";
}

}
?>
```

Comment: You will need to apply the escaping to every value, including `gender` etc

Comment: Is there a question? Or just posting for the archive?

Comment: @Brad I just wanna check that this method is safe. @Pekka but gender is selected using a drop-down menu so I don't think it's a problem right? Or is it possible to change the value using javascript injection?

Comment: Anything coming through $_POST or $_GET could be compromised.  You should escape everything.

Comment: curl (and lots of other software) can issue any GET or POST you like - including injecting gender.

Comment: @Samir you have to distrust every incoming value, no matter what form element is used to fill it on client side. They can be freely manipulated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user will never see the "database problem" message, as the script will `die()` out if the query fails. As well, you're embedding HTML into the message, but are not building a proper HTML-format email. Some mail clients may be smart enough to figure out there's HTML and render it as such, but that's just luck.

The hash you generate is limited to generating only 1001 hashes. Given the birthday paradox, after 38 people sign up, the odds of a collision are 50%. After 100 people, the odds are 99.29%. Instead of hashing a random number, do something like:

```
$hash = md5(serialize($_POST) . $some_other_stuff_in_case_POST_is_empty);
```

Comment: I don't get it, so it should be something like $hash=md5(serialize(what should go here, which $_POST?) and what's with the some_other_stuff ... Sorry if I seem like a noob

Comment: I don't know what you want to use the hash for it, but generating the same hash for multiple people undoubtedly is not a good idea, so you have to use a better source of data for building the hash. Hence using serialize on the $_POSt array - it'll convert that array into a plaintext string, which you can then hash. The $some_other_stuff is there to add more data to the string to randomize the source data even more.

Comment: The hash is used to verify the e-mail, so could I use something like $hash=md5(serialize($_POST['password']) for example, and use that to verify the email?

Comment: No, because it's possible two people will use the same password, leading to the same has. You want the hashes to be unique.

Comment: You most likely don't want to base the hash on anything guessable. It's not likely someone would know how your hash verification system works, but nothing says you have to use user-provided data to generate the hash. Generate something unique on the server and use that instead.

Comment: Could you give me an example on how to generate something unique? I'm really new to this, sorry if I'm annoying you or smthn.

Comment: try using the ID of the newly entered user record and the current timestamp, and add some secret text of your own. A quote, a favorite poem passage, etc... If you're on a unix/linux box, you can read a chunk of data from /dev/urandom to get a cryptographically 'good' chunk of random data and after base64-encoding, could use that as the hash code as well. Plenty of ways of going about it, just don't ever use something that could be easily guessable.

Comment: I mean if it's possible for you to give me some code, thanks in advance. I love the ideas just don't know how to implement them since the user's id isn't in the database yet and I don't really know how to use md5, or any type of hash really. A code example would really help. Thanks.

Comment: Is this ok? $hash = md5(mt_rand(10000,90000));

Comment: No, because again you're basing the hash on a very limited range of numbers. In this case, a possible 80,001 numbers. Use data source(s) which are guaranteed to be unique each time.

Comment: What you can do is insert the user's record, retrieve the ID with mysql_insert_id(), then update the record with the generated hash as a second step. It doesn't have to be done as a single step. If you're using InnoDB tables, you can even do it in a transaction to keep the new record from being used until the hash has been generated/inserted.

Comment: yea but I mean how will the code look like $hash=md5($dbarray['id'].'this is a piece of text')
Is this correct?

Comment: Pretty much. the `md5()` function just accepts a string, so just build up whatever random string you want - it can include bits of the user data, but don't base it EXCLUSIVELY on the user data, or on a fixed range of random numbers. You want guaranteed unique data in there too, otherwise you greatly increase the chance that two different users will receive the same hash.